# Unserialize from WP database, booking dates

Tags: php, wordpress

i have the next info stored in a wp table

```
a:83:{i:0;s:0:"";s:10:"hotel_name";s:10:"Casa Coral";s:13:"hotel_address";s:39:"Constanta, Mamaia Nord, Str. D2, Nr. 28";s:14:"hotel_locality";s:22:"Constanta, Mamaia Nord";s:15:"hotel_telephone";s:12:"0728.330.713";s:11:"hotel_email";s:19:"office@vilacoral.ro";s:13:"hotel_checkin";a:2:{s:4:"from";s:2:"15";s:2:"to";s:2:"16";}s:14:"hotel_checkout";a:2:{s:4:"from";s:2:"11";s:2:"to";s:2:"12";}s:18:"hotel_pets_message";s:16:"Pets are allowed";s:12:"listing_page";s:2:"12";s:12:"booking_page";s:2:"13";s:20:"reservation_received";s:20:"reservation-received";s:12:"pay_endpoint";s:15:"pay-reservation";s:8:"currency";s:3:"IDR";s:17:"currency_position";s:5:"after";s:19:"thousands_separator";s:1:",";s:17:"decimal_separator";s:1:".";s:14:"room_size_unit";s:3:"m²";s:15:"listing_sorting";s:5:"title";s:18:"low_room_threshold";i:1;s:23:"room_catalog_image_size";a:3:{s:5:"width";i:480;s:6:"height";i:294;s:4:"crop";i:1;}s:22:"room_single_image_size";a:3:{s:5:"width";i:1140;s:6:"height";i:699;s:4:"crop";i:1;}s:25:"room_thumbnail_image_size";a:3:{s:5:"width";i:85;s:6:"height";i:85;s:4:"crop";i:1;}s:13:"room_lightbox";s:1:"1";s:12:"booking_mode";s:14:"manual-booking";s:30:"booking_additional_information";s:1:"1";s:22:"booking_minimum_nights";i:1;s:20:"booking_hold_minutes";i:120;s:35:"hide_disabled_dates_from_datepicker";s:1:"1";s:34:"allow_checkout_first_disabled_date";s:1:"1";s:16:"payment_gateways";a:1:{s:6:"paypal";s:1:"1";}s:15:"default_gateway";s:6:"paypal";s:14:"paypal_message";s:54:"Pay with PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!";s:14:"stripe_message";s:45:"Pay with your credit or debit card via Stripe";s:19:"emails_admin_notice";s:19:"office@vilacoral.ro";s:16:"emails_from_name";s:10:"Casa Coral";s:25:"emails_from_email_address";s:19:"office@vilacoral.ro";s:11:"emails_type";s:4:"html";s:11:"emails_logo";s:55:"http://vilacoral.ro/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/logo.png";s:18:"emails_footer_text";s:58:"Termeni si conditii: www.vilacoral.ro/termeni-si-conditii/";s:30:"emails_new_reservation_enabled";s:1:"1";s:30:"emails_new_reservation_subject";s:51:"{site_title} - Rezervare noua #{reservation_number}";s:30:"emails_new_reservation_heading";s:14:"Rezervare noua";s:31:"emails_request_received_enabled";s:1:"1";s:31:"emails_request_received_subject";s:35:"Rezervarea dvs. pentru {site_title}";s:31:"emails_request_received_heading";s:14:"Cerere primita";s:36:"emails_confirmed_reservation_enabled";s:1:"1";s:36:"emails_confirmed_reservation_subject";s:35:"Rezervarea dvs. pentru {site_title}";s:36:"emails_confirmed_reservation_heading";s:29:"Va multumim pentru rezervare!";s:28:"emails_guest_invoice_subject";s:46:"Factura pentru rezervare #{reservation_number}";s:28:"emails_guest_invoice_heading";s:46:"Factura pentru rezervare #{reservation_number}";s:36:"emails_cancelled_reservation_enabled";s:1:"1";s:36:"emails_cancelled_reservation_subject";s:54:"{site_title} - Rezervare anulata #{reservation_number}";s:36:"emails_cancelled_reservation_heading";s:17:"Rezervare anulata";s:42:"emails_guest_cancelled_reservation_enabled";s:1:"1";s:42:"emails_guest_cancelled_reservation_subject";s:35:"Rezervarea dvs. pentru {site_title}";s:42:"emails_guest_cancelled_reservation_heading";s:17:"Rezervare anulata";s:22:"seasonal_prices_schema";a:37:{i:1;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-05-11";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-05-12";s:5:"index";s:1:"1";}i:2;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-05-13";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-05-14";s:5:"index";s:1:"2";}i:3;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-05-15";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-05-19";s:5:"index";s:1:"3";}i:4;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-05-20";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-05-21";s:5:"index";s:1:"4";}i:5;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-05-22";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-05-26";s:5:"index";s:1:"5";}i:6;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-05-27";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-05-28";s:5:"index";s:1:"6";}i:7;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-05-29";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-06-02";s:5:"index";s:1:"7";}i:8;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-06-03";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-06-04";s:5:"index";s:1:"8";}i:9;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-06-05";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-06-09";s:5:"index";s:1:"9";}i:10;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-06-10";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-06-11";s:5:"index";s:2:"10";}i:11;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-06-12";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-06-16";s:5:"index";s:2:"11";}i:12;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-06-17";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-06-18";s:5:"index";s:2:"12";}i:13;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-06-19";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-06-23";s:5:"index";s:2:"13";}i:14;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-06-24";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-06-25";s:5:"index";s:2:"14";}i:15;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-06-26";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-06-30";s:5:"index";s:2:"15";}i:16;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-07-01";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-07-02";s:5:"index";s:2:"16";}i:17;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-07-03";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-07-07";s:5:"index";s:2:"17";}i:18;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-07-08";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-07-09";s:5:"index";s:2:"18";}i:19;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-07-10";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-07-14";s:5:"index";s:2:"19";}i:20;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-07-15";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-07-16";s:5:"index";s:2:"20";}i:21;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-07-17";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-07-21";s:5:"index";s:2:"21";}i:22;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-07-22";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-07-23";s:5:"index";s:2:"22";}i:23;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-07-24";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-07-28";s:5:"index";s:2:"23";}i:24;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-07-29";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-07-30";s:5:"index";s:2:"24";}i:25;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-07-31";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-08-04";s:5:"index";s:2:"25";}i:26;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-08-05";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-08-06";s:5:"index";s:2:"26";}i:27;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-08-07";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-08-11";s:5:"index";s:2:"27";}i:28;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-08-12";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-08-13";s:5:"index";s:2:"28";}i:29;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-08-14";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-08-18";s:5:"index";s:2:"29";}i:30;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-08-19";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-08-20";s:5:"index";s:2:"30";}i:31;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-08-21";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-08-25";s:5:"index";s:2:"31";}i:32;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-08-26";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-08-27";s:5:"index";s:2:"32";}i:33;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-08-28";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-09-01";s:5:"index";s:2:"33";}i:34;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-09-02";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-09-03";s:5:"index";s:2:"34";}i:35;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-09-04";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-09-08";s:5:"index";s:2:"35";}i:36;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-09-09";s:2:"to";s:10:"2017-09-10";s:5:"index";s:2:"36";}i:37;a:3:{s:4:"from";s:10:"2017-09-11";s:2:"to";s:10:"2018-02-28";s:5:"index";s:2:"37";}}s:22:"booking_months_advance";i:0;s:20:"booking_arrival_date";i:0;s:22:"booking_maximum_nights";i:0;s:21:"disabled_dates_schema";a:0:{}s:27:"room_unavailable_visibility";i:0;s:14:"paypal_sandbox";s:1:"1";s:20:"hotel_accepted_cards";a:4:{s:10:"mastercard";s:1:"1";s:4:"visa";s:1:"1";s:7:"maestro";s:1:"1";s:6:"visa_e";s:1:"1";}s:12:"paypal_email";s:0:"";s:17:"paypal_page_style";s:0:"";s:17:"stripe_form_image";s:0:"";s:22:"stripe_live_secret_key";s:0:"";s:27:"stripe_live_publishable_key";s:0:"";s:22:"stripe_test_secret_key";s:0:"";s:27:"stripe_test_publishable_key";s:0:"";s:10:"paypal_log";i:0;s:15:"stripe_testmode";i:0;s:10:"stripe_log";i:0;s:10:"terms_page";s:3:"521";s:28:"emails_guest_invoice_enabled";i:0;s:14:"hotel_postcode";s:0:"";s:9:"hotel_fax";s:0:"";s:18:"price_num_decimals";i:0;s:10:"hotel_pets";i:0;s:19:"enforce_ssl_booking";i:0;s:19:"unforce_ssl_booking";i:0;}
```

And when i try to print dates as a table i get an error using:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $mydata = $row['option_value'];
    $data = unserialize($mydata);
    $tabel = $data['seasonal_prices_schema'];
    foreach($tabel as $linie) {

        $from = $linie['from'];
        $to = $linie['to'];

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $from . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $to . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';

    }

}
```

The error is: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()` in `x.php on line 102`

```
-> foreach($tabel as $linie)
```

When i paste the following stored dates into $mydata = ''; it prints it, but when i've put the info from db isnt working.

Sorry for my english, if you have any idea.

***EDIT:***

I think i figured why isnt working, first of all it dosnt sees it as an array if it gets it from data base, if i copy paste from database on $mydata it prints the table. I think the problem is s:3:"m²"; that "2".

***THE FIX:***
I've put this after making connection to DB. and fixed the problem with the "m²"

```
if($link->set_charset("utf8")){
   // rest of the code
}
```

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

Well that is simple to explain here. Your string is: `s:22:"seasonal_p...`, what says: String with 22 charackters and content ...

So that is not an array you can loop over.

To unserialize an array, your string must start with: `a:32:{s:22:...}`, so in this case the strign in the database might be currupted.

Just try https://de.functions-online.com/unserialize.html with your string posted and you will see that it just returns a string.

By the way: The unserialize function returns false in case of an error. So you cannot distiguish between:

```
$val = unserialize(serialize(false));
```

and

```
$val = unserialize('##'); //invalid string
```

**UPDATE**

Again, looking at the result reveals what happens: Now you are unserializing an array, but that is deeply nested and contains other arrays with either numeric or string keys, so you cannot use an array as string.

Comment: I've update my db stored info. With full serialized it's working with your link. So isnt corrupted, isnt it?

Comment: Check output: http://ideone.com/uYZPNv, the code it's working but it cant parse it well from DB. from `"room_size_unit";s:3:"m²"` to `"room_size_unit";s:3:"m�";`